# In an OpenVPN network, Windows clients cannot access the host and other clients

Tags: ubuntu, windows, vpn, openvpn, linux-networking

I have set up an OpenVPN network and I'd like to let every client in the network be able to connect to each other, ie. servers `10.8.0.1`, `10.8.0.2` and `1.8.0.3` should be able to communicate over VPN and clients (running on various platforms) with IPs `10.8.0.10`, `10.8.0.11`, `10.8.0.12` should able to connect to all servers.

I have already set up servers `10.8.0.1` and `10.8.0.2` running Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and they seem to work properly, but I can't get a client running Windows with IP `10.8.0.10` to connect to both servers - connections seem to timeout.

Here's the `server.conf` running on 10.8.0.1:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/staticclients
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

There's no static IP definition in `staticclients` for the Windows client.

Here's the `client.ovpn` that I run on my Windows PC:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote serverx.startup.io 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

It connects properly, gets an IP assigned, but it can't connect to any IP in the network.

Here's the result of `route print -4` ran on the client:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.17     10
         10.8.0.8  255.255.255.252         On-link         10.8.0.10    276
        10.8.0.10  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.8.0.10    276
        10.8.0.11  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.8.0.10    276
```

What's wrong with my setup? Why I can't connect to the OpenVPN host and the second server from the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suprisingly, the solution was to run OpenVPN as an admin, which is stated *somewhere* in the OpenVPN docs. You don't have to use it with `dev tap`, so it's not enforced by default.

Answer (score 0):

Your subnet is wrong

`10.8.0.8  255.255.255.252         On-link         10.8.0.10    276`

10.8.0.1 and 10.8.0.2 apear on the different network to the system
Therefore, all packets are routed to the default gateway 192.168.1.1

[This page](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/install.html?start=1) explains why do you get that subnet mask

> There are some caveats to be aware of when using
>   "tun" style devices on Windows: the --ifconfig endpoints chosen must
>   be the two "middle" addresses in a 255.255.255.252 subnet.

Try `dev tap`

Upd: oh, you figured it out by yourself.
windows route command requires elevation, so you weren't getting correct routes.